# How to initialize a binding Bool value in a SwiftUI view

Tags: swiftui

***Revised Example***

Based on the thoughtful response from @pawello2222 I received in the comments below I have revised an example to demonstrate the issue I am wrestling with.

In order to demonstrate the issue I am having I am using 2 views a parent and a child. In my code code the parent view executes multiple steps but sometimes the animation subview is not visible in the first step. However when it does become visible the animation has already taken on the appearance of the end state. You can see this behavior in the following example.

*Parent View*

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State var firstTime = true
@State var breath = false

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        
        //            This subview is not displayed until after the first time
        
        if !firstTime {
            SecondView(breath: $breath)
        }
        Spacer()
        
        //            A button click simulates the steps in my App by toggling the @Binding var
        Button("Breath") {
            withAnimation {
                self.breath.toggle()
                self.firstTime = false
            }
        }
        //            This vies shows what happens when the subview is being displayed with an intial state of false for the @Binding var
        Spacer()
        SecondView(breath: $breath)
    }
}
```

}

Here is the subview containing the animation and using a @Binding var to control the animation appearance.

```
struct SecondView: View {
@Binding var breath: Bool

var body: some View {
    Image(systemName: "flame")
        .resizable()
        .rotationEffect(.degrees(breath ? 360 : 0), anchor: .center)
        .scaleEffect(breath ? 1 : 0.2)
        .opacity(breath ? 1 : 0.75)
        .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 2))
        .foregroundColor(Color.red)
}
```

}

When you execute this the first time thru the top subview is not being displayed and when you click the button the lower subview executes the expected animation and then toggles the firstTime var so that the top subview becomes visible.  Notice that the animation is fully expanded and if I was to then have another step (click) with the same value of true for the @Binding property the view would not change at all.  This is the issue I am wrestling with.  I would like to keep the subview from being at the end state if the first step is one that has toggled the Bool value even if the subview was not being displayed. In other words I would like to only initialize the subview when it is actually being displayed with a value of true so that the animation will always start out small.

This is why I was hoping to have the subview initialized the Binding var to false until it actually gets invoked for the first time (or to reset its state to the shrunk version of the animation) whichever is more feasible.

Comment: Would you show minimal reproducible example code? Otherwise it is just a guessing, like below, and you, most probably, will not have answer like you expected.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you may want to initialise `_breath` with the provided parameter:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var breath: Bool

    init(breath: Binding<Bool>) {
        _breath = breath
    }
}
```

However, if you want to use a constant value (in your example `false`) you can do:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var breath: Bool

    init(breath: Binding<Bool>) {
        _breath = .constant(false)
    }
}
```

But then, why do you need the `breath: Binding<Bool>` parameter?

---

**EDIT**

Here is an example how to control an animation of a child view using a `@Binding` variable:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var breath = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Breath") {
                withAnimation {
                    self.breath.toggle()
                }
            }
            SecondView(breath: $breath)
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct SecondView: View {
    @Binding var breath: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: "flame")
            .imageScale(.large)
            .rotationEffect(.degrees(breath ? 360 : 0), anchor: .center)
            .scaleEffect(breath ? 1 : 0.2)
            .opacity(breath ? 1 : 0.75)
            .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 2))
    }
}
```

Comment: This view contains an animation that needs to start out with the breath variable set to false and then when the view is called from it's parent the Binding variable will be toggled to true and the animation will work as expected.  If I do not initialize to false and the parent view calls it with a value of true then the animation ends up already expanded.  So I want to force the variable to start with a value of false and then have it toggled to true.

Comment: @lrreynolds I recommend you to remove the `breath` variable completely and start the animation in `.onAppear` of the child view.

Comment: I tried setting the value to false in .onappear() but this does not work because the value true is being passed in before the .onappear() code is executed and hence the animation stays small for the first cycle.  It works properly is the initial value of the property is false and then it is toggled to true.  This can be done with a state property if this view was not getting called from a parent that needs to toggle the value of this variable.

Comment: @lrreynolds I updated my answer with a short demo explaining how to start animations in `onAppear`.

Comment: I think I understand this but the parent view is toggling the breath property several times after the view has appeared so how do I pass in the new values for the scale effect modifier while the view is active?

Comment: @lrreynolds With the updated example you don’t need the breath variable at all (nor init).

Comment: I tried creating a State variable "localBreath" in the child view and set its initial value to false.  Then I set the self.localBreath = self.breath in .onAppear for the view and this gives me what I want which is an animation that starts small and grows as the first step.  But how do I get localBreath to toggle each time breath toggles so that the animation works as it should?  I tired using a computed property but it does not allow an initializer ie. "false" unless I just don't understand how computed properties work (which is entirely possible).

Comment: Bottom line is I really just want to start the view with a var property that is equal to false and then be able to change that property from the parent view.  If I could initialize the Binding properly of breath to false THAT would do the trick.  But this is a variable so would setting it to a constant work?  Also I have five other Binding properties in this view so do I need to initialize them all?

Comment: Tried using your suggestion of using a constant to initialize all the binding var properties but I get this compiler error "Definition conflicts with previous value"  so I am assuming it does not want to see a constant assigned to a var.

Comment: @lrreynolds What you said *I really just want to start the view with a var property that is equal to false and then be able to change that property from the parent view* can't be done. You init your view when it's called from the parent view, not before. You can set the variable to true in onAppear as in the example above. I suggest you run my second example in the playground without modifications, see how it works and only then replace my animation with yours to adapt to your needs.

Comment: Thanks again for trying to help.  As I said my situation is different and although your suggestion works for the actual launch of the child view the parent view needs to be able to control the state of the "animating var" to control the animation that is being presented in the child view which is why I was using a @Binding var in the first place.

Comment: @lrreynolds What we're discussing here goes beyond the scope of your question - looks like it *needs more details or clarity*. If you want you can replace `@State var animating = false` with `@Binding var animating: Bool` and control it from the parent view. I don't understand where is the problem.

Comment: I was already using a @Binding var so that the parent could control the state however, since the child view gets initialized with a True value to start the animation starts out large and and does not rotate for the first cycle.  I do not understand how animation states are maintained by the system for a view. I know if the view starts with an initial value of false and then gets toggled immediately the animation appears to function fine (ie. grows and spins).  But if the view is initialized with true then the animation object is full size and does not spin until the value is toggled again.

Comment: @lrreynolds I took another try at your question, using `@Binding` - please see an updated answer.

Comment: First of all THANK YOU for attempting to help me on this.  It is a bit more complicated than it first appears.  My parent view is triggering multiple "steps" and sometimes the animation view is not even being shown in the first pass.  However the Binding bool value may have been toggled even before it was shown.  This means that the animation has already assumed it's full size and then when it is shown again with a value of true it does nothing until it has been toggled (shrunk down) and then toggled again (it grows).   I have updated my question with a simple example/